# How to send emails with Jenkins using a existing Sendgrid Dynamic Template

Tags: jenkins, sendgrid

I already configured Jenkins to send emails using Sendgrid, it's work fine. But I have some Dynamic Templates on Sendgrid and I want to know, there is anyway to send this e-mails using this templetes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

From what I can tell, the most popular Jenkins extensions that send emails do so over SMTP. [SendGrid does not support sending Dynamic Templates over SMTP](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/how-to-use-a-transactional-template-with-smtp-or-v2). To send Dynamic Templates with SendGrid you need to use the [SendGrid Mail API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/api-getting-started).

So, to send emails with templates from Jenkins you could find or create an extension that sends emails using the SendGrid API.

Comment: Well, I didn't found any extension about this and never created a Jenkins extension, so for now I will probably just find another way to send this e-mails. Thanks!

Comment: Don't the existing ways to send emails from Jenkins come with their own templates already? Are you trying to override what the emails look like?

Comment: Yeah, we already have some default templates on Sendgrid. So I was thinking in keeping using it. But if I can't use then with Jenkins, Iwill probably use our .py to send then. Its just call the .py using the shell on Jenkins. So, its good enought

Comment: Ah, if you can send with your own script, then that sounds like the right approach.